# Meteor performance comparison of publishing static data vs. getting data via HTTP Get request

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor, query-performance

I am building an app that receives a bunch of static data that is read only. The user does not change the data, or send any data to the server. The app just gets the data and presents it to the user in various views.

Like for example a parts list, with part numbers and prices. This data is currently stored in mongoDB.

I have few options for getting the data to the client. I could just use meteor's publication system, and have the client subscribe to the data it needs.

Or I could map all the data the client needs into one JSON file, save the JSON file to Amazon S3, and have the client make simple GET request to grab the data.

If we wanted this app to scale to many, many users, would not using meteor publication be the best? Or would either method be similar in terms of performance? Using meteor publication system would be the easiest, but I am worried that going down this route would lead to performance issues if a lot of clients request the data. If the performance between publishing and get request is about the same, I would just stick with the publication as its the easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case Meteor will provide better performance.  If your data is mostly server to client driven then clients do not have to worry about polling the server and the server will not have to worry about handling the request.

Also Meteor requires very little resources to send data to the client because the connection is persistent. Take an app like code fights which is built on Meteor constantly has thousands of connections to and from it, its performance runs great.

Comment: thanks. yah publishing to minimongo is really nice way to go. It's just that there is still a view that using web socks to send data is less scalable then http get request. But the meteor server is already sending the entire app with javascript css, etc. so why not just send the data too. When thinking about it like this, it doesn't make sense to use s3 to store json file and make a seperate request to s3. Once I have data loaded in minimongo the app doesn't need to make anymore requests. I can even turn reactivity off by setting `reactive: false`

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, if you are ready to serve your static data as a JSON file in a separate server (AWS S3), then it means you do not expect that data to be that big, so that it can be handled in a single file and entirely loaded in client's memory.

In that case, you might even want to reconsider the need to perform any separate request (whether HTTP or Meteor Pub/Sub).

For instance, simply embedding the data in your app, or served through SSR / [Fast Render](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render) package.

Then if you are *really* concerned about your scalability, you might even reconsider the need to use Meteor, since you do not seem to need any client-server interactivity (no real need for Pub/Sub, no reactivity…). After your prototype is ready, you could rework it as a separate and static SPA, so that you do not even need to serve it through Node / Meteor.

Comment: hey thanks this is good info. I will use fast render, seems perfect. The app will have an admin area where an admin can control the data and upload new data into mongoDB. Kind of like a store with product info. Same product info is sent to all clients. But there is an admin area where an admin can edit prices, add new products, etc. These edits do not need to be sent down to the client in realtime, so reactivity is not needed.

Comment: a better analogy would be a digital product catalog instead of a store as a store has a lot of data exchange.